# select 2 recors in case 2 exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 rows

```
code name
1   cake
2   chocolate
```

This query give me both results

```sql
select * from table a  where a.code=2 or a.code =1
```

If one of these records doesn't show, I don't want to retrieve anything.

```sql
select * from table a  where a.code=2 or a.code =1
and exists ( select 1 from table b where a.code=b.code )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT code,
       name
FROM   (
  SELECT a.*,
         COUNT(DISTINCT code) OVER () AS num_codes
  FROM   table_name a
  WHERE  a.code IN (1,2)
)
WHERE  num_codes = 2;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (code, name) AS
SELECT 1, 'cake'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'chocolate' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CODE | NAME |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | cake |
> | 2 | chocolate |

If you:

```sql
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE code = 1;
```

And run the query again, it outputs:

> | CODE | NAME |
> | --- | --- |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7f2c21b7360a09f4b5a64a5ef3c7cce4)*

Answer (score 0):

Simple check the `count distict`

```
select * from tab1
where code in (1,2) 
and (select count(distinct code) from tab1 where code in (1,2)) = 2;
```

If you want to discard the case where the table has duplicated rows, e.g. `1,1,2`

add an other predicate filter

```
 and (select count(*) from tab1 where code in (1,2)) = 2
```

Comment: I am checking this one